# Run rules on database using rule engine

Tags: redhat-decision-manager

Is there a way where we can define the rules in rule engine like REDHAT decision manager and implement those rules on the tables in databases .

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I have tried defining simple rule in decision manager, deploying it and calling the rule via REST API . It's just I am not sure if we can run these rules on databases directly.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?